# We're testing advertisements on Photography

Tags: discussion

My name is Juan M and I'm one of the community managers here on the network. You can read more about some of what I'm working on [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313084/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network-part-2).

For several years we've had [advertising on technology-related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263678/1438). But [many of our sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) aren't about technology at all, so we haven't sold ads for them. That hasn't been a hardship since Stack Exchange sites require only a small investment from the company to set up and keep live. Thanks entirely to the efforts of your community, this site has become an amazing resource on the internet. Generating revenue from non-technology sites will enable us to dedicate more resources to meeting your needs so this is **good news**.

The test starts May 21 and our advertising team will be monitoring to see how ads are performing. We don't know how many ads will run on this site. It could be just a few or a bit more. In either case, these ads will be carefully vetted and we'll be keeping watch to continue to provide good content.

If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question and tagging it with [advertisements](/questions/tagged/advertisements). This is a work in progress and we are expecting a time of learning and refinement as we move forward.

Comment: ads but I see no "Reduce ads" 200rep milestone privilege? Same on workplace SE

Comment: @jhamon Correct. For the time of the experiment we will not have the reduced ads option.  After we collect necessary data and metrics, we can begin that conversation.

Comment: Are you planning on actually answering questions tagged with `advertisements`?

Comment: @JuanM Where and in what form will the ads appear? I have not seen any ads.

Answer (score 4):

Does this "good news" mean that we might get some resources or features to help us with attracting users interested in the "non-technology" aspects of photography? Because that's precisely what we've been struggling with.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what getting resources will include. :)

Comment: @Juan Can you elaborate on what those might be?

Comment: We want to help the community define it's thematic principles and help to bring in more on-topic material that the community is asking for.

Comment: --> https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6917/1943