# "Good news" and non-technology

Tags: discussion, actually-about-photography, advertisements

Does this "[good news](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6913/1943)" mean that we might get some resources or features to help us with attracting users interested in the "non-technology" aspects of photography? Because that's precisely what we've been struggling with.

What might those resources and features be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split this answer up into multiple ones for a new question designed specifically for it: [What can Stack Exchange do improve this site to better build a photography community of practice here?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/what-can-stack-exchange-do-improve-this-site-to-better-build-a-photography-commu/6938#6938)

Answer (score 1):

The resources that SE brings will be distributed amongst the networks sites.  We are interested in looking at increasing headcount with Community Managers, Developer, etc. These positions will bring additional changes, features, and upgrades to the network.  We're also looking at making potential partnerships with companies for fun things like contests, giveaways, and special deals.

We'll know more as we go further down the line on this experiment. However, I'm interested in knowing what suggestions you have in particular!

Comment: Sure -- I'll put suggestions in another answer to this question.

Comment: Which partnerships are being looked at for driving photo.se engagement?